# redirect based on directory in path via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Via .htaccess, how do you redirect this

```
http://www.somedomain.com/de/foo
```

to this:

```
http://www.de-domain.com/foo
```

The redirection should depend on the second parameter, in the example above "de".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the server configuration you should be able to do this on the `.htaccess` for `somedomain.com`. If this works appropriately you might try `[R=301,L]` to make the redirection permanent:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?somedomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*) http://www.$1-domain.com/$2 [R,L]
```

Comment: I've made it even simpler: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^de/(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Your answer was very helpful!